# Actionscript - move, rotate, and scale an Image and place it centered at a given point

Tags: actionscript, rotation, pivot, center, move

I have a `spark.components.Image`, which is a rectangle and I would like to rotate it by a random angle, move it so as its center is a given point (100,200), and also scale it.

So far, I've tried this

```js
var rotate:Rotate = new Rotate(rect);
rotate.angleBy = Math.random()*100;

var move:Move = new Move(rect);
move.xTo = 100;
move.yTo = 200;

var scale:Scale = new Scale(rect);
scale.scaleXTo = 0.44;
scale.scaleYTo = 0.44;

move.play();
scale.play();
rotate.play();
```

but the problem is that the top-left corner seems to be at the point (100,200). Any ideas how to center it?

I've been reading about pivot points and registration points but I'm still not able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making the "Registration" point of the Image at the center ?

Comment: Hi! I didn't know how to change the "registration" point, because they are not exposed. Instead, I placed the Image inside a container, set its transformX/transformY properties to the center of the image,  and then rotated it. Thanks!

Comment: So everything is ok now?